# On Banach space $X$, does there exist a map similar to $1/z$ that maps elements with very large norm close to elements with norm $0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Basically, I want to ask is there a continuous mapping $F$ from the Banach space $X$ to its closed unit ball such that $||F(x_n)|| \to 0$ as $||x_n|| \to \infty$ kind of like the stereographic projection. For the complex plane, the mapping I am looking for would just be $1/z$ but we clearly can't do that for an arbitrary Banach space since elements may not be invertible. Does such a transformation exist?

Comment: let $v\in X$, $0<\|v\|\leq 1$ be a fixed element. Let $F(x)=(\max\{1,\|x\|\})^{-1} v$.

Comment: There is inversion in the unit sphere: $x \mapsto x/\|x\|^2$. It behaves very much like $z \mapsto 1/z$ (or more precisely, $z \mapsto 1/\overline{z}$), and like this map, it isn't continuous at $0$. It's also not particularly interesting when $X$ is a general Banach space. However, if $X$ is an inner product space, it is intimately connected with stereographic projection, even to the point of preserving generalised spheres. In fact, one can define this map in terms of stereographic projection and vice-versa. Maybe this might be of some use to you?